# Accessing a local website on an iPad

Tags: website, ipad

On my computer I have been learning HTML, CSS and JavaScript and have  made a web app for the iPad, however I have no way of visiting the site on Safari. I have an external Network drive however when I try that address, Safari alerts "Cannot open the page because it is a local file". I know I could get web hosting but this is not ideal.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I don't know how many ISP's still do this but don't you get some free webspace with your internet subscription?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iPad, but not interacting with a PC.

Comment: Try here: http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally HTML, CSS and Javascript shouldnt need a websserver.

How are you accessing the file?

Try installing apache on your computer, place the files in webroot and visit the computers IP from the Ipad ( something like 192.168.1.x).

I think that would work for you.

Comment: I've installed XAMPP so I could learn PHP and SQL and when I access the files on the computer the address is localhost/

Comment: It works! I just used my local IP address then the file path following localhost

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) for hosting online...

It has a public folder where you can host your files and the whole public>website folder, with index.html page acts as a website. And it's free! 5GB of cloud storage free on dropbox.

5GB free on [Google drive](https://drive.google.com/) too, and that too can be used as a webserver by setting the folder properties to public.